# input date must be not be greater than current date in bootstrap datepicker [dd-M-yyyy] format

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

my input textbox

```
<input  type="text" id="dateOfDiagnosisTextbox" class="form-control" />
```

This is my jquery

```
$('#dateOfDiagnosisTextbox').datepicker({
            format: "dd-M-yyyy",
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        });
```

Date of textbox should be a valid date format (dd-M-yyyy) and must be not be greater than current date otherwise system should display appropriate error message.

Comment: simplest way `maxDate : 'now'`

Comment: Check the documentation https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max . Your maxDate should be Current date.

Comment: Removed my incorrect answer, both comments above are very much correct.  For date format you need to specify the parameter like : `dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' `

Comment: `maxDate : 'now'` property not available in Bootstrap Datepicker  @ Curiousdev

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/or3jabbv/

```
 $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ maxDate: "now" });
 } );
```

Comment: the question asked for bootstrap datepicker ,but you given answer for Jquery UI Datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dateOfDiagnosisTextbox').datepicker({
     format: "dd-M-yyyy",
     autoclose: true,
     todayHighlight: true,
     endDate: new Date()
});
```

Comment: I didn't find any endDate property in http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: What about input date must be a future Date ?